# Meaning of 'shot havoc'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In D. H. Lawrence one can find a lot of unusual constructions.

Here's the one (from his essay on Herman Melville's *Moby Dick*):

> He was a mystic who raved because the old ideal guns **shot havoc**. The guns of the 'noble spirit'. Of 'ideal love'.

What does 'shot havoc' mean, especially in this context?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It means rather than bullets, when you pulled the trigger on these guns, they expelled (shot) havoc (instead of lead). It’s metaphorical. He gives two examples of the kind of havoc these guns shot: noble spirit and ideal love. He’s saying these kinds of forces, these sentiments, are liable to cause havoc. It’s being a little ... well, ironic isn’t the right word, but it’s the one that comes to mind.